# why my oxi file still in the IN Folder and integrated 2 times and more in the data base?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an automaton to integrate my files (.oxi = xml file ) in the DB, but i have a problem that the same file is integrated 2 times and more .

I did many precaution to prevent that using the move function from the IN path  to the archive path after the integration but it still not working .

After that i used the copy to the archive path and delete the  file from the IN path after the integration succed but it still not working.

Can any body  explain to me what the problem exactly ?

```
public class Doc
    {
        public XmlDocument xDoc { get; set; }
        public String Path { get; set; }
        public String file_name { get; set; } 
    }


public class Job
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String PathIn { get; set; }
        public String PathArchive { get; set; }
        public String PathError { get; set; }
        public String StatutLotOut { get; set; }
    }





  // start the job called every period by the timer


      public void start()
        {
            //General.addLog("hello, i am started");
            UpdateText();
            List<Job> jobs = get_jobs();
            foreach (Job job in jobs)
            {
                List<Doc> docs = new List<Doc>();
                //read all xml document inside the IN forlder path in   
                docs = gen.read_oxi(job);
                foreach (Doc doc in docs)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        TransferOpex.doc = doc;
                        TransferOpex.job = job;
                        xml_serialisation(doc.xDoc, job);
                        gen.moveDocToArchiverPath();
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        General.addText("\n error : " + ex.ToString());
                        General.addLog(ex.ToString());
                        gen.moveDocToErrorPath();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   public void moveDocToArchiverPath()
        {
            if (File.Exists(TransferOpex.doc.Path))
            {
                string Path2 = Path.Combine(TransferOpex.job.PathArchive, TransferOpex.doc.file_name + ".oxi");
                if (File.Exists(Path2))
                    File.Delete(Path2);

                File.Copy(TransferOpex.doc.Path, Path2,true);
                addText("\n file " + TransferOpex.doc.Path + " copied to Archive path at" + DateTime.Now);
                General.addLog("\n file " + TransferOpex.doc.Path + " copied to Archive path at" + DateTime.Now);
                if (File.Exists(TransferOpex.doc.Path))
                {


                    while (!IsFileReady(TransferOpex.doc.Path)) {

                    }

                    File.Delete(TransferOpex.doc.Path);
                    addText("\n file " + TransferOpex.doc.Path + " deleted from in path at" + DateTime.Now);
                    General.addLog("\n file " + TransferOpex.doc.Path + " deleted from in  path at" + DateTime.Now);
                }

            }
        }

        public static bool IsFileReady(string filename)
        {
            // If the file can be opened for exclusive access it means that the file
            // is no longer locked by another process.
            try
            {
                using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                    return inputStream.Length > 0;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I use timer to check every time if there are new files in the IN Forlder

```
SetTimer();




 private void SetTimer()
        {
            TextAffichage += "\n The application started at " + DateTime.Now;
            General.addText("\n Timer = " + gen.ReadSetting("Timer") + "ms");
            General.addText("\n configPath = " + configPath);
            General.addText(" \n connectionStrings = " + gen.ReadSetting("connectionStrings"));
            General.addLog("Started");
            UpdateText();
            // Create a timer with a x second interval, you can find the value of x inside app.config.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(int.Parse(gen.ReadSetting("Timer")));
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            start();
        }
```

And this the function that make the integration in the DB

```
public void xml_serialisation(XmlDocument doc, Job job)
        {
            Lot lot = new Lot();
            classes.Image image = new classes.Image();
            XmlNodeList batchs = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch");
            XmlNode batch = batchs[0];
            String BatchIdentifier = batch.Attributes["BatchIdentifier"] != null ? batch.Attributes["BatchIdentifier"].Value : "Unknow value";
            String NUM_LOT = BatchIdentifier;
            String TransportId = batch.Attributes["TransportId"] != null ? batch.Attributes["TransportId"].Value : "Unknow value";
            String NUM_SCANNER = TransportId;
            String StartTime = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].Attributes["StartTime"] != null ? doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].Attributes["StartTime"].Value : "Unknow value";
            //String ID_lot = DateTime.Parse(StartTime).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "" + NUM_LOT + "" + NUM_SCANNER;
            String ID_lot = TransferOpex.doc.file_name;
            String NUM_NB_IMAGE = doc.GetElementsByTagName("EndInfo")[0].Attributes["NumPages"] != null ? doc.GetElementsByTagName("EndInfo")[0].Attributes["NumPages"].Value : "Unknow value";
            String EndTime = doc.GetElementsByTagName("EndInfo")[0].Attributes["EndTime"] != null ? doc.GetElementsByTagName("EndInfo")[0].Attributes["EndTime"].Value : "Unknow value";
            String JobName = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].Attributes["JobName"] != null ? doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].Attributes["JobName"].Value : "Unknow value";
            String ImageFilePath = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].Attributes["ImageFilePath"] != null ? doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].Attributes["ImageFilePath"].Value : "Unknow value";

            //String OperatorName = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].Attributes["OperatorName"] != null ? doc.GetElementsByTagName("Batch")[0].Attributes["OperatorName"].Value : "Unknow value";
            String OperatorName = gen.ReadSetting("OperatorName");

            //instatiate Class lot 
            lot.TXT_TYPE_LOT = JobName;
            lot.ID_LOT = long.Parse(ID_lot);
            lot.NUM_NB_IMAGE = int.Parse(NUM_NB_IMAGE);
            lot.DAT_DEBUT_NUM = DateTime.Parse(StartTime);
            lot.DAT_FIN_NUM = DateTime.Parse(EndTime);
            lot.ID_STATUT = int.Parse(job.StatutLotOut);// attention!!!!!!!!!!!, faut le recuperer de la configuration
            lot.NUM_SCANNER = int.Parse(NUM_SCANNER);
            lot.TXT_OPERATEUR = OperatorName;
            XmlNodeList pages = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Page");
            List<classes.Image> images = new List<classes.Image>();
            List<Icr> icrs = new List<Icr>();

            foreach (XmlNode page in pages)
            {
                String BatchSequence = page.Attributes["BatchSequence"] != null ? page.Attributes["BatchSequence"].Value : "Unknow value";
                XmlNodeList imgs = null;
                if (page.SelectNodes("Image") != null && page.SelectNodes("Image").Count > 0)
                {
                    imgs = page.SelectNodes("Image");
                }

                String AuditTrail = "";
                if (page.SelectNodes("AuditTrail") != null && page.SelectNodes("AuditTrail").Count >0)
                {
                    AuditTrail = page.SelectNodes("AuditTrail")[0].Attributes["Text"] != null ? page.SelectNodes("AuditTrail")[0].Attributes["Text"].Value : "Unknow value";
                }

                String PageName = page.Attributes["PageName"] != null ? page.Attributes["PageName"].Value : "Unknow value";
                // get node list from the config.xml file
                XmlNodeList Recos = gen.getNodelList("Reco");
                foreach (XmlNode Reco in Recos)
                {
                    String Balise = Reco.Attributes["Balise"] != null ? Reco.Attributes["Balise"].Value : "";
                    String TagValue = Reco.Attributes["TagValue"] != null ? Reco.Attributes["TagValue"].Value : "";
                    String TypeIcr = Reco.Attributes["TypeIcr"] != null ? Reco.Attributes["TypeIcr"].Value : "";
                    XmlNodeList Balises = page.SelectNodes(Balise) != null ? page.SelectNodes(Balise) : null;

                    if (Balises != null)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode balise in Balises)
                        {
                            //instatiate Class Icr 
                            String Index = balise.Attributes["Index"] != null ? balise.Attributes["Index"].Value : "";
                            Icr icr = new Icr();
                            // this instance will be saved
                            icr.save_it = true;
                            icr.ID_LOT = lot.ID_LOT;
                            icr.NUM_SEQUENCE = int.Parse(BatchSequence);
                            icr.NUM_INDEX = Index;
                            if (Balise == "Barcode")
                            {
                                icr.TXT_ICR = balise.Attributes["Value"].Value;
                                if (balise.Attributes["Type"] != null)
                                {
                                    if (balise.Attributes["Type"].Value == TagValue)
                                    {
                                        icr.TXT_TYPE = TypeIcr;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        icr.TXT_TYPE = "unknow value";
                                        // prevent the instance to be saved in the DB
                                        icr.save_it = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (Balise == "markDetect")
                            {
                                icr.TXT_ICR = balise.Attributes["Result"].Value;
                                icr.TXT_TYPE = Reco.Attributes["TypeIcr"].Value;
                            }
                            else if (Balise == "Micr")
                            {
                                icr.TXT_ICR = balise.Attributes["Value"].Value;
                                icr.TXT_TYPE = Reco.Attributes["TypeIcr"].Value;
                            }
                            else if (Balise == "OCR")
                            {
                                icr.TXT_ICR = balise.Attributes["Value"].Value;
                                icr.TXT_TYPE = Reco.Attributes["TypeIcr"].Value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                icr.save_it = false;
                            }
                            if (icr.TXT_ICR == "")
                            {
                                icr.save_it = false;
                            }

                            if (icr.save_it) icrs.Add(icr);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(imgs !=null)
                foreach (XmlNode img in imgs)
                {
                    String Filename = img.Attributes["Filename"] != null ? img.Attributes["Filename"].Value : "Unknow value";
                    if (Filename == "" && gen.ReadSetting("acceptBlankImage") == "0")
                    {
                        General.addLog("can't add blank image( image without path ), in order to do that please change the value of acceptBlankImage to 1 ");
                        //create exceprion intentionally outside of the catch
                        int i = 0;
                        int j = 1 / i;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        String Length = img.Attributes["Length"] != null ? img.Attributes["Length"].Value : "Unknow value";
                        String Height = img.Attributes["Height"] != null ? img.Attributes["Height"].Value : "Unknow value";
                        image = new classes.Image();
                        image.ID_LOT = lot.ID_LOT;
                        image.TXT_CHEMIN_IMAGE = ImageFilePath + "\\" + Filename;
                        String machine = gen.ReadSetting("machine");
                        //String index = "";

                        //if (machine == "IBML")
                        //{
                        //    index = Filename[0] + "" + Filename[1];
                        //}
                        //else if (machine == "OPEX")
                        //{
                        //    String file_name_without_extension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Filename);
                        //    int Lenght = file_name_without_extension.Length;
                        //    int firstrightcharindex = Lenght - 1;
                        //    index = file_name_without_extension[firstrightcharindex] + "";
                        //}


                        String expression = gen.ReadSetting("EXPRESSION_NUM_TYPE_PAGE");
                        String index = "";
                        if (expression[0] == 'g' || expression[0] == 'G')
                        {
                            int gauche = (int)char.GetNumericValue(expression[1]);//donne le number de caratère faut le recuperer à droite
                            for (int i = 0; i < gauche; i++)
                            {
                                index += Filename[i] + "";
                            }
                        }

                        else if (expression[0] == 'd' || expression[0] == 'D')
                        {
                            int droite = (int)char.GetNumericValue(expression[1]);//donne le number de caratère faut le recuperer à droite
                            String file_name_without_extension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Filename);
                            int Lenght = file_name_without_extension.Length;
                            int firstrightcharindex = Lenght - 1;

                            for (int i = firstrightcharindex; i > firstrightcharindex - droite; i--)
                            {
                                index += file_name_without_extension[i] + "";
                            }
                            index = General.Reverse(index);
                        }

                        image.TXT_ENDOS = AuditTrail;
                        image.NUM_SEQUENCE = int.Parse(BatchSequence);
                        image.NUM_PAGE = int.Parse(BatchSequence);
                        image.NUM_TYPE_PAGE = int.Parse(getTypeImage(PageName, index)); //attention !!!!!!, faut le recuperer de la configuration 
                        image.ID_STATUT = int.Parse(gen.ReadSetting("ID_STATUT")); //attention!!!!!!!, faut le recuperer de la configuration 
                        image.Length = Length;
                        image.Height = Height;
                        images.Add(image);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            DB.Database db = new DB.Database();
            // save into data base
            db.save_to_db(lot, images, icrs);
        }

        //get the job list  from config.xml and serialize into object
        public List<classes.Job> get_jobs()
        {
            XmlNodeList jobsNodelist = gen.getNodelList("Job");
            List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();
            foreach (XmlNode j in jobsNodelist)
            {
                Job job = new Job();
                job.Name = j.Attributes["Name"] != null ? j.Attributes["Name"].Value : "unknow value";
                job.PathArchive = j.Attributes["PathArchive"] != null ? j.Attributes["PathArchive"].Value : "unknow value";
                job.PathIn = j.Attributes["PathIn"] != null ? j.Attributes["PathIn"].Value : "unknow job";
                job.StatutLotOut = j.Attributes["StatutLotOut"] != null ? j.Attributes["StatutLotOut"].Value : "unknow job";
                job.PathError = j.Attributes["PathError"] != null ? j.Attributes["PathError"].Value : "unknow job";
                jobs.Add(job);
            }
            return jobs;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, just a small tip for asking questions here on Stack.. Don't add tags for languages that aren't directly part of the question :-) I know that c# and VB.Net are similar, and you want your question to reach the widest audience,  but the two languages have substantial differences and there is less knowledge cross-over than you might think - Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your notes, i apreciate that